# Parsing JSON from PHP to PHP

Tags: php, json

Here is a code from test.php file

```
    <?php
    function test_function(){

            $return = $_GET;
            $KeyWord = test_input($return["keyword"]); //  need to validate the keyword first!!! test_input($_GET["KeyWord"]);
            $app_id = $return["appid"];
            $sortOrder = $return["SortSelection"];
            $NumPerPage = $return["ResultsNum"];
            $condition = "";
            $index = 0;
            if(!empty($return["condition"])){
                $count = 0;
                $condition = "&itemFilter($index).name=Condition";
                foreach($return["condition"] as $selected) {
                    $condition.="&itemFilter($index).value($count)=$selected";
                    $count++;
                }
                $index++;
            }       
            $minPrice = "";
            if(!empty($return["priceLow"])){
                $minPrice = "&itemFilter($index).name=MinPrice&itemFilter($index).value(0)={$return["priceLow"]}";
                $index++;
            }
            $maxPrice = "";
            if(!empty($return["priceHigh"])){
                $maxPrice = "&itemFilter($index).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter($index).value(0)={$return["priceHigh"]}";
                $index++;
            }
            $buyingFormat = "";
            if(!empty($return["BuyFormat"])){
                $buyingFormat = "&itemFilter($index).name=ListingType";
                $count = 0;
                foreach($return["BuyFormat"] as $selected) {
                    $buyingFormat.="&itemFilter($index).value($count)=$selected";
                    $count++;
                }
                $index++;
            }
            $seller = "&itemFilter($index).name=ReturnsAcceptedOnly";
            if(!empty($return["seller"])){
                $seller.="&itemFilter($index).value(0)=true";
            }
            else{
                $seller.="&itemFilter($index).value(0)=false";
            }
            $index++;
            $FreeShippingOnly = "&itemFilter($index).name=FreeShippingOnly";
            if(!empty($return["FreeShippingOnly"])){
                $FreeShippingOnly.="&itemFilter($index).value(0)=true";
            }
            else{
                $FreeShippingOnly.="&itemFilter($index).value(0)=false";
            }
            $index++;
            $ExpeditedShippingType = "";
            if(!empty($return["ExpeditedShippingType"])){
                $ExpeditedShippingType="&itemFilter($index).name=ExpeditedShippingType&itemFilter($index).value(0)=Expedited";
                $index++;
            }
            $MaxHandlingTime = "";
            if(!empty($return["MaxHandlingTime"])){
                $MaxHandlingTime = "&itemFilter($index).name=MaxHandlingTime&itemFilter($index).value(0)={$return["MaxHandlingTime"]}";
                $index++;
            }
            $SellerInfo = "&outputSelector(0)=SellerInfo";
            $PictureURLSuperSize = "&outputSelector(1)=PictureURLSuperSize";
            $StoreInfo = "&outputSelector(2)=StoreInfo";
            $pageNumber = $return["pageNumber"];
        $URL ="http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?siteid=0&SECURITY-APPNAME=" . $app_id . "&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&keywords=";

    $URL=$URL.$KeyWord."&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=".$NumPerPage."&paginationInput.pageNumber=".$pageNumber."&sortOrder=".$sortOrder.$condition.$minPrice.$maxPrice.$buyingFormat.$seller.$FreeShippingOnly.$ExpeditedShippingType.$MaxHandlingTime.$SellerInfo.$PictureURLSuperSize.$StoreInfo;//
    $XML = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($URL));
        $json['ack']  = "$XML->ack";
            $paginationOutput = $XML->paginationOutput; 
            $json['resultCount']  = "$paginationOutput->totalEntries";// variables inside "" cannot be longer than 2!!
            $json['pageNumber']  = "$paginationOutput->pageNumber";
            $json['itemCount']  = "$paginationOutput->entriesPerPage";
            $json['totalPages']  = "$paginationOutput->totalPages";
            $i = 0;
                    foreach($XML->searchResult->item as $item){
                        $json['item'][$i]['basicInfo']['title'] = "$item->title";
                        $json['item'][$i]['basicInfo']['viewItemURL'] = "$item->viewItemURL";
                        $json['item'][$i]['basicInfo']['galleryURL'] = "$item->galleryURL";
                        $json['item'][$i]['basicInfo']['pictureURLSuperSize'] = "$item->pictureURLSuperSize";
        $i++;
        }
     echo json_encode($json);//return the JSON

}
```

How do I decode this code in another PHP file. I used ajax method but then  I need to parse this code using PHP.
I know json_decode function but it needs to have a .json file and I tried json_decode method but it but it didn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what your question or problem is.

Comment: You don't need a .json file in order to apply json_decode. I'm assuming you are using a separate server for the other php file, right ? If that's so, you can just use file_get_contents from the current script, and then apply json_decode

Comment: No I am using same server. can you please show me one example please? for instance I want to parse $json['item'][$i]['basicInfo']['title'] = "$item->title"; in another file how do I do this... thank you in advance